# Problems in mapping indices using awk

Tags: bash, awk

Hi all I have this data files

File1

```
1   The hero
2   Chainsaw and the gang
3   .........
4   .........
```

where the first field is the id and the second field is the product name

File 2

```
The hero 12
The hero 2
Chainsaw and the gang 2
.......................
```

From these two files I want to have a third file

File 3

```
The hero 12 1
The hero 2 1
Chainsaw and the gang 2 2
.......................
```

As you can see I am just adding the indices reading from file 1

I used this method

```
awk -F '\t' 'NR == FNR{a[$2]=$1; next}; {print $0, a[$1]}' File1 File2 > File 3
```

where I am creating this associated array using File 1 and doing just lookup using product names from file 2

However my files are huge, I have like 20 million product names and this process is taking a lot of time. Any suggestions, how I can speed it up?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awk:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{p=$1; $1=""; sub(/^ +/, ""); a[$0]=p;next} {q=$NF; $NF=""; sub(/ +$/, "")}
     ($0 in a) {print $0, q, a[$0]}' f1 f2
The hero 12 1
The hero 2 1
Chainsaw and the gang 2 2
```

Comment: Is it scalable to 20 million rows. Also could you explain what the above code is doing?

Comment: the code which I pasted in my question does work for like million rows,up to 7 millions but for this particular data I have has like 25 million rows and it is not working. Plus when I create the associate array, it's keys are huge strings too

Comment: It works with your example provided, I don't have 20 million records file to test it.

Answer (score 0):

The script you posted won't produce the output you want from the input files you posted so let's fix that first:

```
$ cat file1
1   The hero
2   Chainsaw and the gang

$ cat file2
The hero 12
The hero 2
Chainsaw and the gang 2

$ awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR{map[$2]=$1;next} {key=$0; sub(/[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+$/,"",key); print $0, map[key]}' file1 file2
The hero 12 1
The hero 2 1
Chainsaw and the gang 2 2
```

Now, is that really too slow or were you doing some pre or post-processing and that was the real speed issue?

The obvious speed up is if your "file2" is sorted then you can delete the corresponding map[] value whenever the key changes so your map[] gets smaller every time you use it. e.g. something like this (untested):

```
$ awk -F'\t' '
NR==FNR {map[$2]=$1; next}
{ key=$0; sub(/[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+$/,"",key); print $0, map[key] }
key != prev { delete map[prev] }
{ prev = key }
' file1 file2
```

Alternative approach when populating map[] uses too much time/memory and file2 is sorted:

```
$ awk '
{   key=$0
    sub(/[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+$/,"",key)
    if (key != prev) {
        cmd = "awk -F\"\t\" -v key=\"" key "\" \047$2 == key{print $1;exit}\047 file1"
        cmd | getline val
        close(cmd)
    }
    print $0, val
    prev = key
}' file2
```

Comment: The problem is creating just the associative array is killing me awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR{map[$2]=$1;next} file1 file2. It takes for ever, In file 1 the fields are separated by tab. There are two fields

Comment: there is no way to make populating that array go any faster. I tried it myself and it was taking a long time and seemed to be slowing down every other process on my laptop so I killed it after 5 mins. The alternative which I just updated my answer to include is not to use read file1 into memory but instead to search "file1" for each key from file2. It may work better for you just due to not requiring so much memory.

Answer (score 0):

From comments you're having scaling problems with your lookups.  The general fix for that is to merge sorted sequences:

```
join -t $'\t' -1 2 -2 1 -o 1.2,2.2,1.1 \
    <( sort -t $'\t' -k2 file1) \
    <( sort -t $'\t' -sk1,1 file2)
```

I gather Windows can't do process substitution, so you have to use temporary files:

```
sort -t $'\t' -k2 file1 >idlookup.bykey
sort -t $'\t' -sk1,1 file2 >values.bykey

join -t $'\t' -1 2 -2 1 -o 1.2,2.2,1.1 idlookup.bykey values.bykey
```

If you need to preserve the value lookup sequence use `nl` to put line numbers on the front and sort on those at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is performance then try this `perl` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -l 

use strict;
use warnings;

my %h;
open my $fh1 , "<", "file1.txt";
open my $fh2 , "<", "file2.txt";
open my $fh3 , ">", "file3.txt";

while (<$fh1>) {
    my ($v, $k) = /(\d+)\s+(.*)/;
    $h{$k} = $v;
}

while (<$fh2>) {
    my ($k, $v) = /(.*)\s+(\d+)$/;
    print $fh3 "$k $v $h{$k}" if exists $h{$k};
}
```

Save the above script in say `script.pl` and run it as `perl script.pl`. Make sure the file1.txt and file2.txt are in the same directory as the script.

Comment: It is also holding the lookup array into memory. How come it will work?

Comment: My fields are tab separated. Can you change the line where you parse file1 and split it into key value pair? I am not much into perl

Comment: Sorry may be I was too pessimistic. But I wanted to know how come what you did will be different than creating the associative array using awk. I don't mean to be rude. But just curious. I have run your code too

Comment: I told you it wouldn't work, it has already frozen my laptop. Please start giving sensible suggestions guys